# Evitar que o scroll role enquanto o Bootstrap Modal estiver aberto

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal

Como fazer para evitar que o scroll role enquanto o Modal Dialog do Bootstrap estiver aberto?

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button id="fechar" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">Fechar</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você deseja que o Modal não role junto a página ou que a Página a não role de forma alguma?

Comment: Que a página não role de forma alguma.

Answer (score -1):

Quando o modal é exibido, o bootstrap adiciona a classe *modal-open* automaticamente, e remove quando ele é ocultado.
Colocando no seu css esse trecho:

*body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}*

**OBS:** Não funciona corretamente no Safari e algumas versões mais antigas do Internet Explorer.